# emmet conflicting with snippets visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I type an emmet string and press tab visual studio replaces it with just the main element. Then i realized it was preferning the the snippet that it was auto suggesting. Is there a way around this or fix it? I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community edition on windows 7 64bit if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I was using another plugin called Viasafora that colors braces and makes it easier to to see your indentations it had a default option for showing completions ans you type.  I had to go turn it off.